# Setting a keyboard shortcut in Windows 10 which opens a particular program in the foreground without launching the same program again

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, window

I would like to have a shortcut that I set which does the following in the Windows 10:

*The shortcut launches the particular program that I set for that shortcut if the program is not launched already. However if the program has already been launched in the background, I just open it in the foreground by this shortcut.*

I know that in Windows 10 I can set my own shortcut for any program to open that program. However this shortcut only launches the new session of that program even if the same program is already launched in the background. Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: Your goal might be easier to understand if you specify which program you are wanting to launch

Comment: For example I pin to the taskbar in the Windows 10 an application like Chrome. Than I want a shortcut which opens that already opened Chrome window in the foreground.

Comment: This can be scripted and run from a shortcut, however please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: So there is no way for a lay person to set such a shortcut without the necessity to learn the coding?

Comment: It already does that. Create a shortcut to Notepad, right click - Properties. Assign Ctrl+Alt+N as a hotkey. Press Ctrl+Alt+N will start Notepad AND assign a window hotkey to Notepad's window. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+N again will switch to the open Notepad.

Comment: Actually that is the problem. It always launches a new session, even if opened in the background.

Comment: Not with notepad.